# Inconsistent connectivity via WiFi manager in ESP8266

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am facing a peculiar problem. The below code snippet connects to new WiFi network. **No hard-coded ssid or password in the program**. I am using **AsyncWifiManager** and **AsyncWebServer** modules. When I am connecting to my home WiFi router providing ssid and password in autoconnect portal, NodeMCU is getting connected and the server is working fine. But whenever I am changing the WiFi, connecting to my mobile phone hotspot, then server is not running, though I am getting local IP address in Serial Monitor.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>          
#include <ESPAsyncTCP.h>          

#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>     
#include <ESPAsyncWiFiManager.h> 

#include <FS.h>
#include <Wire.h>

   AsyncWiFiManager wifiManager(&server,&dns);

  // To clean previous settings. Use one time, then comment
  // wifiManager.resetSettings();



  // set custom static ip for portal
  IPAddress staticIP(192,168,0,20);  //ESP static ip
  IPAddress gateway(192,168,0,1); //IP Address of your WiFi Router (Gateway)
  IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0); //Subnet mask
  wifiManager.setSTAStaticIPConfig(staticIP, gateway, subnet);


// Open WiFi Setup portal
  wifiManager.autoConnect();

  Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");


  // Print ESP32 Local IP Address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());


  WiFi.begin();


 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
}
```

I am programming the NodeMCU board via Arduino IDE.

Comment: Are you sure those IP setting are valid in your mobile phone hotspot?

Comment: @gre_gor No, I just realized it now after your comment. Thanks. When I am connecting to mobile HotSpot it showing different IP for default gateway. But in that scenario how to achieve universal connectivity to any WiFi network?

Comment: Don't set a static IP and let DHCP do its thing?

Comment: In that case how can I communicate to the server all the time as it will change? In my case I have hosted a mini server with ESP8266 and communicating with it via mobile app, so if the IP is not static then how can I communicate all the time. Is there by any chance some DNS library available which will dynamically map the associated IP? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

As your code uses fix parameters for IP/subnet/gateway you have to setup your different hotspots accordingly or you have the following options to choose from as you connect your ESP8266 server to different hotspots:

- always being in the same network/subnetwork (all hotspots are part of a local network) you can use fix IP-addresses for all devices irrelevant of the hotspot you connect to
- If you do not want to use above (=fix IP for all devices): Set the DHCP server to always give the same IP addresses to the NodeMCUs based on their MAC addresses.
- You use mDNS and give the ESP8266 a fixed name and call via http://nyPreferredESP.local (allthough the IP varies) and use on your Android phone something [like this APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anubisg1.multicast_new&hl=en)
- If you want to work with changing gateways (Devices not on the same net/subnet, access over the internet): This would require something a little more robust. Use a Dynamic DNS service along with a domain name. The Dynamic DNS will update your DNS records in almost real time if your gateway address changes. [Example here](https://hackaday.com/2017/04/12/diy-dyndns-with-esp8266-and-dweets/)

The complexity of the solution results from the factor always in the same network/subnet and a fixed gateway or everything (except MAC-address and name of the device are fix) and the rest may be variable. Read some basics about [setting up a local network here](https://www.broadbandchoices.co.uk/how-to/how-to-set-up-a-local-area-network)