# ESP8266 do not connect with LED strip

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I was trying to make [this](https://github.com/AnshumanFauzdar/Sound-and-music-reactive-ESP8266-WS2812B) It's not working.

I have connected NodeMCU v3 ESP8266 data 1 > data input WS2812B and that's all but the strip doesn't react for some reason.

Wiring is good for sure, the strip is working with Arduino but not with ESP8266

The blue LED on NodeMCU v3 ESP8266 is lighted up.

I tried to connect NodeMCU v3 ESP8266 to my phone hotspot and it did connect.

I never tried using this module before.

Here is my config file and .ino:

cfg.py

```cpp
"""Settings for audio reactive LED strip"""
from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import division
import os

DEVICE = 'esp8266'
"""Device used to control LED strip. Must be 'pi',  'esp8266' or 'blinkstick'

'esp8266' means that you are using an ESP8266 module to control the LED strip
and commands will be sent to the ESP8266 over WiFi.

'pi' means that you are using a Raspberry Pi as a standalone unit to process
audio input and control the LED strip directly.

'blinkstick' means that a BlinkstickPro is connected to this PC which will be used
to control the leds connected to it.
"""

if DEVICE == 'esp8266':
    UDP_IP = '192.168.1.2'
    """IP address of the ESP8266. Must match IP in ws2812_controller.ino"""
    UDP_PORT = 7777
    """Port number used for socket communication between Python and ESP8266"""
    SOFTWARE_GAMMA_CORRECTION = False
    """Set to False because the firmware handles gamma correction + dither"""

if DEVICE == 'pi':
    LED_PIN = 18
    """GPIO pin connected to the LED strip pixels (must support PWM)"""
    LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000
    """LED signal frequency in Hz (usually 800kHz)"""
    LED_DMA = 5
    """DMA channel used for generating PWM signal (try 5)"""
    BRIGHTNESS = 255
    """Brightness of LED strip between 0 and 255"""
    LED_INVERT = True
    """Set True if using an inverting logic level converter"""
    SOFTWARE_GAMMA_CORRECTION = True
    """Set to True because Raspberry Pi doesn't use hardware dithering"""

if DEVICE == 'blinkstick':
    SOFTWARE_GAMMA_CORRECTION = True
    """Set to True because blinkstick doesn't use hardware dithering"""

USE_GUI = True
"""Whether or not to display a PyQtGraph GUI plot of visualization"""

DISPLAY_FPS = True
"""Whether to display the FPS when running (can reduce performance)"""

N_PIXELS = 100
"""Number of pixels in the LED strip (must match ESP8266 firmware)"""

GAMMA_TABLE_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'gamma_table.npy')
"""Location of the gamma correction table"""

MIC_RATE = 44100
"""Sampling frequency of the microphone in Hz"""

FPS = 60
"""Desired refresh rate of the visualization (frames per second)

FPS indicates the desired refresh rate, or frames-per-second, of the audio
visualization. The actual refresh rate may be lower if the computer cannot keep
up with desired FPS value.

Higher framerates improve "responsiveness" and reduce the latency of the
visualization but are more computationally expensive.

Low framerates are less computationally expensive, but the visualization may
appear "sluggish" or out of sync with the audio being played if it is too low.

The FPS should not exceed the maximum refresh rate of the LED strip, which
depends on how long the LED strip is.
"""
_max_led_FPS = int(((N_PIXELS * 30e-6) + 50e-6)**-1.0)
assert FPS <= _max_led_FPS, 'FPS must be <= {}'.format(_max_led_FPS)

MIN_FREQUENCY = 200
"""Frequencies below this value will be removed during audio processing"""

MAX_FREQUENCY = 12000
"""Frequencies above this value will be removed during audio processing"""

N_FFT_BINS = 24
"""Number of frequency bins to use when transforming audio to frequency domain

Fast Fourier transforms are used to transform time-domain audio data to the
frequency domain. The frequencies present in the audio signal are assigned
to their respective frequency bins. This value indicates the number of
frequency bins to use.

A small number of bins reduces the frequency resolution of the visualization
but improves amplitude resolution. The opposite is true when using a large
number of bins. More bins is not always better!

There is no point using more bins than there are pixels on the LED strip.
"""

N_ROLLING_HISTORY = 2
"""Number of past audio frames to include in the rolling window"""

MIN_VOLUME_THRESHOLD = 1e-7
"""No music visualization displayed if recorded audio volume below threshold"""
```

led.ino

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <Hash.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <NeoPixelBus.h>

// Set to the number of LEDs in your LED strip
#define NUM_LEDS 100
// Maximum number of packets to hold in the buffer. Don't change this.
#define BUFFER_LEN 1024
// Toggles FPS output (1 = print FPS over serial, 0 = disable output), Don't change this
#define PRINT_FPS 1

//NeoPixelBus settings
const uint8_t PixelPin = 3
;  // make sure to set this to the correct pin, ignored for Esp8266(set to 3 by default for DMA)

// Wifi and socket settings - Your Wifi Details
const char* ssid     = "SAGEM_FB00";
const char* password = "4EE37746";
unsigned int localPort = 7777;
char packetBuffer[BUFFER_LEN];

// LED strip
NeoPixelBus<NeoGrbFeature, NeoEsp8266Uart1800KbpsMethod> ledstrip(NUM_LEDS);

WiFiUDP port;

// Network information - Check by typing ipconfig in CMD
// IP must match the IP in config.py
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 2);
// Set gateway to your router's gateway
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
    Serial.println("");
    // Connect to wifi and print the IP address over serial
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.print("Connected to ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
    port.begin(localPort);
    ledstrip.Begin();//Begin output
    ledstrip.Show();//Clear the strip for use
}

uint8_t N = 0;
#if PRINT_FPS
    uint16_t fpsCounter = 0;
    uint32_t secondTimer = 0;
#endif

void loop() {
    // Read data over socket
    int packetSize = port.parsePacket();
    // If packets have been received, interpret the command
    if (packetSize) {
        int len = port.read(packetBuffer, BUFFER_LEN);
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i+=4) {
            packetBuffer[len] = 0;
            N = packetBuffer[i];
            RgbColor pixel((uint8_t)packetBuffer[i+1], (uint8_t)packetBuffer[i+2], (uint8_t)packetBuffer[i+3]);
            ledstrip.SetPixelColor(N, pixel);
        } 
        ledstrip.Show();
        #if PRINT_FPS
            fpsCounter++;
            Serial.print("/");//Monitors connection(shows jumps/jitters in packets)
        #endif
    }
    #if PRINT_FPS
        if (millis() - secondTimer >= 1000U) {
            secondTimer = millis();
            Serial.printf("FPS: %d\n", fpsCounter);
            fpsCounter = 0;
        }   
    #endif
}
```

And the second problem is when I check com port monitor I only see reversed question marks.

Comment: you cannot control a led strip by just connecting one pin. please post your code here, not on pastebin. reduce it to a [mcve] and read [ask]. are other sketches running ok on your esp? provide more info

Comment: i do have power connected to led strip and it's my first time when i'm using esp8266

Comment: Your Arduino code doesn't even have the `loop()` function. And I doubt that the static IP config is valid for your hotspot. Did you try any basic example first, to check if its actually a problem with LEDs?

Comment: The leds are working for sure and static ip is correct

Comment: Are you sure about the IP? Can you make at least the build-in LED blink through network? Because [someone else had that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61665434).

Answer (score 1):

You need at least a common ground, see the enclosed circuit:
[image: NodeMCU_WS2812B]

Comment: still didn't fix the issue

Comment: Your program is not complete or a config is missing. Where are the #include libs and the definition of NUM_LEDS.

Comment: I do have everything included and program is flashing without any problems
I just cut this part

Comment: So you know the problem is in that part then solve it yourself

Comment: I mean i didnt post whole file here

Comment: How do you know it's a grounding problem? OP didn't show his connections and the tutorial he followed shows the ground connectied. And if this is a hardware problem, then this question is off-topic and should be closed, not answered.

Comment: The first thing is to rule out hardware the OP obviously from his comment further up had not done so. Now I am waiting for the whole code. I think educating new OPs is more polite than just closing - my 2 cents

Comment: You can point out that in the comments. Answering just makes it harder to delete off-topic questions.